# "message" dinamico do p:confirm - Primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces

Alguém sabe me dizer como faço para alterar o `message` do `<p:confirm>`? Quando clicar no botão quero que o valor do `message` seja o retornado pelo metodo `messageCount()`.

```
...

<p:outputLabel value="Teste:" />                        
<p:inputText value="#{testeController.campoTeste}" id="campoTeste"/>

...

<p:commandButton value="Ok" action="#{testeController.cadastrarTest()}">
    <p:confirm header="Confirmação" message="Confirmar?"/>
</p:commandButton>

 ...

<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
    <p:commandButton value="Sim" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
    <p:commandButton value="Não" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
</p:confirmDialog>



...


public Integer messageCount() {
    return count++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare uma variavel no seu bean, `String message = "Confirmar?"`
Coloque um id no p:confirm, `id="message"` e também `value="{{testeController.message}}"`

Essa parte do código `{{testeController.message}}` chama o método na sua classe TesteController, `getMessage()`.

Altere/implemente o método `getMessage()` para efetuar as modificações que você precisa

Comment: Certo... Mas acho que este é o problema. Eu preciso usar uma mensagem que vai variar dependendo do clique no botão. Neste exemplo que você me passou vai ser sempre o valor definido no inicio. Como posso fazer para mudar o valor da `String message` a cada clique?

Comment: Vou editar a resposta

Comment: Mas a `action` vai ser executada somente depois que eu aceitar `p:confirmDialog`. Não é? Caso seja isso, eu preciso mudar a mensagem antes de eu dar o submit no form. Obrigado

Comment: Quando você quer mudar a mensagem??? Pelo que entendi.. a cada vez que você clicasse no botão iria mudar a mensagem.... como vc quer entao ?

Comment: Vamos ver se consigo me explicar melhor agora... No exemplo que postei tem o botão **Ok**, quando clico nele é mostrada `p:confirm` **message** com as opções **Sim** e **Não**. Quando clico em **Sim** executa `action="#{testeController.cadastrarTest()}"`. Bom isso é a forma normal como funciona. O que preciso, considerando o que descrevi, é que ao clicar no botão **Ok** antes de executar o `cadastrarTest()` eu possa ir até a controller e buscar o texto atualizado para usar na tela de **Confirmação**. Obrigadoo

Comment: vou editar a resposta então

Comment: Perfeito... agora ok... Vou "trabalhar" no `getMessage()`. Muito obrigado...